# JS Lodash - How to refactor a curried function with _.curry()?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, lodash

### Introduction

I had this code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, Button } from 'react-native';

export default function App() {
  const myMethod = (name) => {
    console.log(`Hello ${name}!`);
  };

  return (
    <View>
      <Button onPress={() => myMethod("Victor")}>
        Press me!
      </Button>
    </View>
  );
}
```

Then, I decided to refactor it using curried functions. Like this:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, Button } from 'react-native';

export default function App() {
  /**
   * @param {string} name - The name.
   * @returns {Function} Curried function.
   */
  const myMethod = (name) => {
    return () => {
      console.log(`Hello ${name}!`);
    }
  };

  return (
    <View>
      <Button onPress={myMethod("Victor")}>
        Press me!
      </Button>
    </View>
  );
}
```

As you can see, the way I am invoking the method has changed, as I am returning a function instead of `void` in `myMethod`. That's cool, it works... every time the button is pressed, my method is invoked.

Check this snack: https://snack.expo.dev/Rx3iBVT_W

### Problem

Now, I am trying to refactor the refactored code using [`curry` from Lodash](https://lodash.com/docs/#curry).

This is what I have tried:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, Button } from 'react-native';
import { curry } from 'lodash';

export default function App() {
  const myMethod = curry((name) => {
    console.log(`Hello ${name}!`);
  });

  return (
    <View>
      <Button onPress={myMethod("Victor")}>
        Press me!
      </Button>
    </View>
  );
}
```

But for some reason, this is not working. The method is not executed every time the button is pressed... Instead, it is invoked when the component mounts.

How can I solve it?

Check this snack: https://snack.expo.dev/bna6cLkhp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm afraid you've misunderstood [currying](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying) (which is easily done, and lots have — including myself).

> Then, I decided to refactor it using curried functions. Like this:

That code doesn't curry a function. It just creates a closure over the `name` parameter. That's called [partial application](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_application).

Lodash's [`curry`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#curry) does currying instead. The function it returns will do its work as soon as all of its parameters are satisfied — as soon as you provide it the name it needs, in your case. So it does its work when you do `myMethod("Victor")`, not later:

```js
const myMethod = _.curry((name) => {
    console.log(`Hello ${name}!`);
});

myMethod("Victor");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.21/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

If you want it to wait for a second argument, you need to tell `curry` that your function requires two arguments, and then provide it with two arguments (one at a time in this case):

```js
const myMethod = _.curry((name) => {
    console.log(`Hello ${name}!`);
}, 2);
// ^−−−−−−− tells `curry` this function needs two arguments, even
//          though the function itself says it only needs 1

console.log("Supplying the first argument");
const fn = myMethod("Victor");
console.log("Supplying the second argument");
fn({}); // <== Note the argument, we need to supply one
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.21/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

That works because we've told `curry` your function needs to have two arguments, and `myMethod("Victor")` only gives it one, so it returns another function that will do its work when you give it the other argument. `onPress` will give it a second argument because it passes the event object to it.

Check out the `curry` documentation for more examples.

That said, I wouldn't use `curry` here. You're not really currying, so it's a bit of a misuse. I'd use your partial application solution, if I had to bake the name into the function at all.

Comment: "*That code doesn't curry a function. It just creates a closure over the name parameter. That's called partial application.*" another name for this is [thunk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thunk) (a name I find rather funny). In short, a thunk is a form of delayed computation. It's a function that takes no parameters and when you run it does *something*. The idea is that you want that *something* to happen later, not now. And maybe you also want it repeatable. A function that takes arguments can be made into a thunk with partial application: `thunkFn = _.partial(fn, onlyArg)`